# Can't find right regex in Python! I need to filter only names that present a sub-pattern once

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of column names from a data frame:

```
['s_0','s_1','s_2','s_0_m','s_1_m','s_2_m']
```

I need to make a comprehension list and select only the names without m at the end (s_0, s_1...) or only the names with m at the end (s_0_m, s_1_m etc).

So I thought it would be something like

```
[col for cols in df.columns if re.search(regex,col)]
```

But I can't figure out the regex expression, please help me!

Comment: You could use `'[^m]$'` (if you don't care about matching empty string). Or you could just do `if not col.endswith('m')`.

Comment: If the `_m` part is always at the end, I would use the `endswith` string method:

    `with_m = [x for x in col_list if x.endswith('_m') == True]` and 
    `no_m = [x for x in col_list if x.endswith('_m') == False]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why you would use regex when you can do this in pure Python very quickly.

```
# Initialization
col = ['s_0','s_1','s_2','s_0_m','s_1_m','s_2_m']

# for i in col, return if the last letter (i[-1]) is not equal (!=) to "m"
print([i for i in col if i[-1] != "m"])

# ['s_0', 's_1', 's_2']
```